# How can I access data on Charge Only mode (Phone's screen is non-functional!)?

Tags: file-transfer, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 3. The phone was accidentally dipped into the water which rendered it unusable. I left the phone to dry in a rice bag for 5 days and then took it out and charged it.

The phone booted and was working until I put it to charge. The moment I switched on the power adapter, the screen went black and then the backlight came on.

I remember that before the incident, the phone was in charge-only mode and as the screen is non-functional, I cannot change the mode now. I was wondering, if there is any way, I could access, and recover my data before I give it to any authorized Service Center personnel, who says that there is no chance that the motherboard is fine.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, is phone even alive or it just turn on backlight?

Comment: As far as I know, the phone is alive. When I long press the power button, the phone vibrates which indicates that it is still booting, I guess!

Answer (score 1):

There's little chance you can do that in normal system. But you can do it in (custom) recovery.

If you already have a custom recovery flashed, then skip this step. Boot it into fastboot (bootloader) and flash a custom recovery in.

Then boot into the recovery and you can access it using ADB shell. You can use `adb pull` to retrieve data from your phone.

Comment: Could you provide me with a walkthrough of the process, and how could I do it without using the screen! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know how it goes with Xiaomi but when you want to flash recovery you need to unlock bootloader, and when you do that phone will perform factory reset itself so you will have nothing to save. However you could be able to use "fastboot boot recovery.img" where recovery.img is file name of custom recovery you trying to boot, and then maybe try with ADB

Comment: @J This specific phone does not have a locked bootloader, IIRC.

Comment: @iBug Is it? Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 does not have a locked bootloader? So are there any chances I would be able to recover my data?